# Can't load Twitter JSON feed within script tag

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I have this strange issue I can't overcome apparently, I am trying to retireve a Twitter JSON feed using the script tag at the bottom of my page:

```
<script src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/haunted85.json?count=15&callback=listTweets" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I want the data to be handed over a callback function I have named `listTweets`. The thing is if I load my page and try to get the output in my Chrome console tab via javascript function, then I get a `Failed to load resource` error, but if I manually copy and enter the URI in the address bar, I am returned all the Twitter data in the browser. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does `listTweets` get called at all? Try and inspect the "Network" tab in Chrome Inspector/Firebug. Did the twitter API call return `200 OK`? I dynamically inserted that script element into this StackOverflow page, and it successfully called `listTweets`.

Comment: I just tried it locally and it tries to call listTweets, both running as localhost and as a local file. Whereabouts are you including the script?

Comment: `listTweets` doesn't get called at all because there's no event triggering it, I suspect and I've just looked in the Network tab and the twitter api returns just `(failed)` with no error code.

Comment: @Lewis I am including it just before the closing `</body>` tag at the end of my page. I have also tried to place it elsewhere in the page, but no change whatsoever.

Comment: Why don't you use a standard JSONP-Call to fetch the data? Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hDy3Y/

Comment: @m90: haunted85 *is* using JSONP. You used jQuery.

Comment: @haunted85 Reproduced the environment as you described in your post - still works properly. See [here](http://pastebin.com/6tP3rzHq).

Comment: This is odd. Sounds like a security thing as it works fine on my machine in latest chrome. Maybe try putting a defer attribute on the script to see if it makes a difference although I doubt it.

Comment: @JulianH.Lam just copied your code and pasted it in a fresh page... still encountering this issue. Could it be a problem of my local developing environment?

Comment: At this point, I would assume so. Your browser may be rejecting external javascript scripts from loading (though I can't imagine why). Did you try on a different browser?

Comment: @JulianH.Lam yes, same problem, although looking closely in firebug I am getting `x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block` and a `403 Forbidden` error... so is it a security matter?

Comment: @haunted85 try copying and pasting to a fresh HTML page with a dummy listTweets handler and open it directly from your hard disk to see if you get the same issue, then try the same thing on your local environment.